# Laravel Eloquent: Should I append values from the model or controller?

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent, model, append

I have a model with `id`, `name`, and `cost`.

```
protected $table = 'has_costs';
protected $fillable = [
    'id','name','cost'
];
```

Then I also used append to add new columns, `cost_under` and `cost_over`, which basically does simple calculation from cost.

```
protected $appends = ['cost_over','cost_under'];
```

Should I do the calculation in the model like this:

```
public function getCostOverAttribute()
{
    $costOver = (20/100)*cost;
    return $this->attributes['over'] = $costOver;
}

public function getCostUnderAttribute()
{
    $costUnder = (80/100)*cost;
    return $this->attributes['under'] = $costUndr;
}
```

Or should I still do it in the controller to keep it more "MVC"?

The actual code is more complex than this example and it takes a lot of time thinking about how to append each values deep inside complex Eloquent `with` queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makes more sense to add `cost_over`and `cost_under` as model properties.

```
public function getCostOverAttribute()
{
    return 20 / 100 * $this->cost;
}

public function getCostUnderAttribute()
{
    return 80 / 100 * $this->cost;
}
```

You can access them `$model->cost_over` and `$model->cost_under`.

Keep your controller clean from internal model's calculations over its data.

Also if you don't want to append these properties each time you instance the model, you can append attributes on the way as `$model->append('cost_over')` in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple.

Keep them in your model, because if you do it right:

- You can then use them in your Eloquent queries
- You can use `$model->costUnder`
- Controllers are more like 'resource managers' rather than 'model descriptors' if you know what I mean.